# .htaccess POST data blocked

Tags: php, .htaccess, post

I send POST data from a form to my root index that will redirect :

```
<form action="index.php?menu=blog&section=admin" method="post">
```

But this lines in .htaccess blok POST data :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'v tried a few other ones but same problem :

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^(.*) www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,NC,P] #Doesn't rewrite "www"
```

There are a few other post with similar problem but I don't find my solution

How can I send POST datas to index.php?menu=blog&section=admin ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules

Rewriting product.php?id=12 to product-12.html

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^product-([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?id=$1
```

Rewriting product.php?id=12 to product/ipod-nano/12.html

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?id=$2
```

Redirecting non www URL to www URL

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^viralpatel\.net$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.viralpatel.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Rewriting yoursite.com/user.php?username=xyz to yoursite.com/xyz

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1
```

Redirecting the domain to a new subfolder of inside public_html

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
  RewriteRule (.*) /new/$1
```